# What is $\xi$ in the definition of the definite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1}f(\xi_n)(x_{n+1} - x_{n}) $  and $\xi_n \in [x_n, x_{n+1}]$

So how I understand it: We could take equivalent distance between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ and then we would get $x_n = a+\frac{n(a-b)}{N}$ and then define like this: $\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1}f(x_n)(x_{n+1} - x_{n}) $

But we cannot do this for every integral, so we do what is written above, we take arbitrary length of the interval $[x_n, x_{n+1}]$ .

However I do not understand why do we need $\xi_n$ to also be a number between the two point, and not just let's say $x_n$ like we used in equivalent distance formula.

Comment: It’s wrong to make it one variable, should be $\xi_n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I will edit, the question remains the same just with $\xi_n$

Comment: The $\xi_n$ are the so called "sample points". In the definition of Riemann sum they are each located somewhere in the associated interval $[x_{n-1},x_n]$ of a partition of the integration interval.

Comment: Fundamentally, when $f$ is continuous, it doesn’t matter which $\xi_n$ you choose. The real problem is when there are discontinuities.

Comment: It would be arbitrary to take $\xi_n = x_n$ when really it's ok for $\xi_n$ to be any point between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$. There would be something aesthetically displeasing about making such an arbitrary choice. Also, when proving the fundamental theorem of calculus it is useful that $\xi_n$ can be any point between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ because the mean value theorem tells us that $f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n) = f'(\xi_n)(x_{n+1} - x_n)$ for some $\xi_n \in (x_n,x_{n+1})$. Then the Riemann sum is a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of variants of the usual definition. [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Similar_concepts) discusses them clearly, including your apparent suggested use of left Riemann sums throughout, which causes no problems since you can always refine tagged partitions to use left Riemann sums. It gives a simple counterexample to using *both* regularly-spaced sample points and left sums simultaneously--the indicator function $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise appears to be integrable over $[0, 1]$ with both restrictions, even though it is not integrable.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) (edited to use $\xi$ rather than $t$):

> One popular restriction is the use of "left-hand" and "right-hand" Riemann sums. In a left-hand Riemann sum, $\xi_i = x_i$ for all $i,$ and in a right-hand Riemann sum, $\xi_i = x_{i + 1}$ for all $i.$ Alone this restriction does not impose a problem: we can refine any
> partition in a way that makes it a left-hand or right-hand sum by
> subdividing it at each $\xi_i.$ In more formal language, the set of all
> left-hand Riemann sums and the set of all right-hand Riemann sums is
> cofinal in the set of all tagged partitions.

The real problem is if you limit yourself to left or right *and* limit your partitions to even partitions, $x_n=a+\frac{b-a}Nn.$ You can either limit your partitions to even partitions, or limit your $\xi_n$ to left or right, but not both.

Rather than pick one way, then prove the other is equivalent, we define with both together, then show this is equivalent to the two (pure left- or right-Riemann sums, or pure even partitions with arbitrary $\xi_n.$)